# vall-e model throws 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'optimizer_name' error while training, how to fix it?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, deep-fake

I'm trying to use the vall-e model available on this github repo: https://github.com/enhuiz/vall-e

I clone the repo with the command
`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/enhuiz/vall-e.git`

I create a virtual environment with the command
`python3 -m venv vall_e_env`

I prepare my environment with the command
`source vall_e_env/bin/activate`
then
`pip install .`

finally I use the commands provided in the read me :
`python -m vall_e.emb.qnt data/test`
`python -m vall_e.emb.qnt data/test`

and finally

```
python -m vall_e.emb.qnt data/test
```

only this last command produces the following error:

```
2it [00:00, 6961.50it/s]
2023-05-31 16:58:32 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
{'</s>': 1, '<s>': 2, 'AH0': 3, 'D': 4, 'ER1': 5, 'HH': 6, 'L': 7, 'OW1': 8, 'W': 9, '_': 10}
2023-05-31 16:58:32 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
{ 'test': 0}
2023-05-31 16:58:32 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
#samples (train): 2.
2023-05-31 16:58:32 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
#samples (val): 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 119, in main
    trainer.train(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/utils/trainer.py", line 125, in train
    engines = engines_loader()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 21, in load_engines
    model=trainer.Engine(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/utils/engines.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 244, in __init__
    self._do_sanity_check()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 974, in _do_sanity_check
    if self.optimizer_name() is not None:
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 628, in optimizer_name
    return (self.client_optimizer.__class__.__name__ if self.client_optimizer else self._config.optimizer_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'optimizer_name'
```

newer error of `python -m vall_e.train yaml=config/test/ar.yml` after the first answer

```
2it [00:00, 6743.25it/s]
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
{'</s>': 1, '<s>': 2, 'AH0': 3, 'D': 4, 'ER1': 5, 'HH': 6, 'L': 7, 'OW1': 8, 'W': 9, '_': 10}
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
{'test': 0}
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
#samples (train): 2.
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - vall_e.data - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
#samples (val): 0.
[2023-05-31 17:25:31,146] [INFO] [comm.py:654:init_distributed] Initializing TorchBackend in DeepSpeed with backend nccl
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - torch.distributed.distributed_c10d - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
Added key: store_based_barrier_key:1 to store for rank: 0
2023-05-31 17:25:31 - torch.distributed.distributed_c10d - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
Rank 0: Completed store-based barrier for key:store_based_barrier_key:1 with 1 nodes.
2023-05-31 17:25:32 - torch.distributed.distributed_c10d - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
Added key: store_based_barrier_key:2 to store for rank: 0
2023-05-31 17:25:32 - torch.distributed.distributed_c10d - INFO - GR=0;LR=0 - 
Rank 0: Completed store-based barrier for key:store_based_barrier_key:2 with 1 nodes.
[2023-05-31 17:25:32,243] [INFO] [logging.py:68:log_dist] [Rank 0] DeepSpeed Flops Profiler Enabled: False
Installed CUDA version 11.5 does not match the version torch was compiled with 11.7 but since the APIs are compatible, accepting this combination
Using /home/leandre/.cache/torch_extensions/py310_cu117 as PyTorch extensions root...
Creating extension directory /home/leandre/.cache/torch_extensions/py310_cu117/fused_adam...
Detected CUDA files, patching ldflags
Emitting ninja build file /home/leandre/.cache/torch_extensions/py310_cu117/fused_adam/build.ninja...
Building extension module fused_adam...
Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
[1/3] /usr/bin/nvcc  -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=fused_adam -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/includes -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O3 -DVERSION_GE_1_1 -DVERSION_GE_1_3 -DVERSION_GE_1_5 -lineinfo --use_fast_math -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -std=c++14 -c /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam/multi_tensor_adam.cu -o multi_tensor_adam.cuda.o 
FAILED: multi_tensor_adam.cuda.o 
/usr/bin/nvcc  -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=fused_adam -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/includes -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O3 -DVERSION_GE_1_1 -DVERSION_GE_1_3 -DVERSION_GE_1_5 -lineinfo --use_fast_math -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -std=c++14 -c /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam/multi_tensor_adam.cu -o multi_tensor_adam.cuda.o 
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:145: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  435 |         function(_Functor&& __f)
      |                                                                                                                                                 ^ 
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:145: note:         ‘_ArgTypes’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:146: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  530 |         operator=(_Functor&& __f)
      |                                                                                                                                                  ^ 
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:146: note:         ‘_ArgTypes’
[2/3] c++ -MMD -MF fused_adam_frontend.o.d -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=fused_adam -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/includes -I/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -fPIC -std=c++14 -O3 -std=c++14 -g -Wno-reorder -DVERSION_GE_1_1 -DVERSION_GE_1_3 -DVERSION_GE_1_5 -c /home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/csrc/adam/fused_adam_frontend.cpp -o fused_adam_frontend.o 
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1900, in _run_ninja_build
    subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 119, in main
    trainer.train(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/utils/trainer.py", line 125, in train
    engines = engines_loader()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/train.py", line 21, in load_engines
    model=trainer.Engine(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e/utils/engines.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 330, in __init__
    self._configure_optimizer(optimizer, model_parameters)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1195, in _configure_optimizer
    basic_optimizer = self._configure_basic_optimizer(model_parameters)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1272, in _configure_basic_optimizer
    optimizer = FusedAdam(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/adam/fused_adam.py", line 72, in __init__
    fused_adam_cuda = FusedAdamBuilder().load()
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/op_builder/builder.py", line 460, in load
    return self.jit_load(verbose)
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/op_builder/builder.py", line 495, in jit_load
    op_module = load(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1284, in load
    return _jit_compile(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1508, in _jit_compile
    _write_ninja_file_and_build_library(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1623, in _write_ninja_file_and_build_library
    _run_ninja_build(
  File "/home/leandre/Info/OpenValue/vall-e/vall_e_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1916, in _run_ninja_build
    raise RuntimeError(message) from e
RuntimeError: Error building extension 'fused_adam'
```

Does anyone know where the error may have come from?

Comment: At this point I'm not able to help you but seems like you have a different CUDA version from the compiled one. I'm not able to tell you if this is a problem, but the problem comes from adam, which is an algorithm for optimization in deep learning. Let's hope someone can help you from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a library that has different version than the repo. Since he's not creating the repo with venv, you are not installing the libraries properly. Try to create a requirements.txt from his setup.py

```
    coloredlogs~=15.0.1
    deepspeed~=0.7.7
    diskcache~=5.4.0
    einops~=0.6.0
    encodec~=0.1.1
    g2p_en~=2.1.0
    humanize~=4.4.0
    matplotlib~=3.6.0
    numpy~=1.23.3
    omegaconf~=2.2.3
    openTSNE~=0.6.2
    pandas~=1.5.0
    soundfile~=0.11.0
    torch~=1.13.0
    torchaudio~=0.13.0
    tqdm~=4.64.1
```

Now, delete your venv, create it again and run `pip -r install requirements.txt`

Comment: Thx for yout answer ! Thanks to the requirements.txt, the error is fixed, but a new one appears, i post it in bellow the first one